# What is the difference between AWS.Logger.Log4net vs AWS.Logger.AspNetCore

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch

This is for AWS cloud watch logging, one of my application is using `AWS.Logger.Log4net` with .NET Framework 4.7 which writes the logs in the AWS cloud-watch environment. We have a new requirement to develop a .NET Core 2.2 console application which needs to be deployed in an AWS batch job.

I am just confused between the `AWS.Logger.Log4net` and `AWS.Logger.AspNetCore` - can the `AWS.Logger.Log4net` be referenced in .NET Core 2.2 for logging, or do I need to use `AWS.Logger.AspNetCore`?

I just tried to reference the `AWS.Logger.Log4net` in the .NET Core application, looks like these Log4net API is not available for .NET Core:

1. XmlConfigurator.Configure();
2. (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

I wanted to know my .Net core app should log the logs in Cloud watch, what can I use `AWS.Logger.Log4net` or `AWS.Logger.AspNetCore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `AWS.Logger.Log4net` works with the Log4net logging interfaces/sinks where `AWS.Logger.AspNetCore` provides a logger that works with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

I would suggest using `AWS.Logger.AspNetCore` since that depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` what the .NET Core libraries use.